# How to get a day of week from civil.Date

Tags: go

How can I get a day of week from civil.Date using the type civil.Date such as Monday, Sunday.

```
    date := civil.Date{
        Year:  2021,
        Month: time.May,
        Day:   1}
```

I am looking for the equivalent to Weekday() function of 'time' package.

Any alternative way is also welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried the `time` package? And `civil` is not part of the standard library, at least link to the docs for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/civil"
)

func main() {
    date := civil.Date{
        Year:  2021,
        Month: time.September,
        Day:   5,
    }

    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, date.String()+"T00:00:00Z")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(t.Weekday().String())

}
```